# Add new field in Add new customer form in backend

Tags: attributes, backend, customer-attribute

I studied regarding how to add new field in registration form for new customer. Got to know that need to add attribute for it. I created a module for it. But now, admin add new customer page shows me this error.

**There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 168844915537**

My module code is as follows:
app/etc/modules/Addattribute_Customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Addattribute_Customer>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <depends><Mage_Customer/></depends>
            </Addattribute_Customer>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

app/code/local/Addattribute/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Addattribute_Customer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Addattribute_Customer>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <addattribute_customer>
                <class>Addattribute_Customer_Helper</class>
            </addattribute_customer>
        </helpers>

        <resources>
            <addattribute_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Addattribute_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </addattribute_customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <addattribute_customer>
                    <file>addattribute_customer.xml</file>
                </addattribute_customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Addattribute_Customer>
                    <files>
                        <default>Addattribute_Customer.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Addattribute_Customer>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Addattribute/Customer/sql/addattribute_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'sales_executive', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Sales_Executive',
    'input'     => 'select',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => true,//or true
    //'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'sales_executive');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

app/code/local/Addattribute/Customer/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Addattribute_Customer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Please give your suggestion or mark my mistake.

Comment: provide var/report/168844915537 file

Comment: "Source model "" not found for attribute "sales_executive"";i:1;s:3340:"#0 /home/kazim_noorani/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model ""...') @GopalPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
```

in config.xml instead of

```
<class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
```

In `app/code/local/Addattribute/Customer/sql/addattribute_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'sales_executive', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Sales_Executive',
    'input'     => 'text',
    "visible"  => true,
    'required'  => true,//or true
    //'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'sales_executive');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```